# django stylesheet donot link with the image file

Tags: css, django, templates, static

In my settings.py I have static setting like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ' '

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

And my project structure is :

```
ProjectName
    app1
    app2
    ProjectName
    static
        css
        js
        images
```

And I have written a css in named style.css :

```
input.search { width: 279px; border: none; background: #fff url(../images/input.gif) no-repeat; padding: 6px 10px; color: #1E67A8; font-weight: bold; }
```

When I do this it didnt display the image that I have assigned in my style.css..

Whats the problem ??

Comment: tell u can access this via url or not ...?  http://localhost:8000/static/images/input.gif

Comment: yeah, The image is accessed from mentioned url...

Comment: then do like same in css .. see my ans below

Answer (score 0):

You may need this in your settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'static',
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'static'),)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the image URL in CSS like

```
input.search { width: 279px; border: none; background: #fff url(/static/images/input.gif) no-repeat; padding: 6px 10px; color: #1E67A8; font-weight: bold; }
```